# How to display maven updates for plugins dependency

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

We can display plugin updates for project by command:

```
mvn versions:display-plugin-updates
```

but how to display updates dependency for plugin which we use?

Eg.
I use `maven-checkstyle-plugin`, so I have:

```
   <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.15</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

I know that `maven-checkstyle-plugin` use old version of `checkstyle`, so I change my pluginManagment to:

```
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.15</version>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
              <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
              <version>6.5</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

So how can I check if checkstyle has new version?

Comment: Have you tried managing the checkstyle dependency using a property for the version, and then calling `mvn version:display-property-updates`. Not sure it'll work, but it's something you can try.

Comment: Yes, `versions:display-property-updates` is working, `versions:update-properties` is working also.

Comment: Does that solve the problem you're having? If so you could consider adding at as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to properties we can use

`versions:display-property-updates` and `versions:update-properties`

Example can look now as below:

```
    <properties>
      <checkstyle.version>6.5</checkstyle.version>
    </properties>
    ...
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.15</version>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
              <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
              <version>${checkstyle.version}</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

---

Thanks to Tim for hint

Comment: Great, glad I could help.. Feel free to accept your own answer using the green check-mark on the left.